# Error 1120 For stage instances

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am getting a number of errors for each of my items, each on different keyframes.

I have "Automatically Declare Stage Instances" turned off so I thought that might be having something to do with it. It is quite annoying. The errors only show up when I test the MainMenu scene, testing the movie has the buttons not animating.

I have tried to fit all the info into some screen shots.

I would appreciate any help you could render. At this point I'm out of ideas.

Errors and Instance Properties
[image: Errors and Instance Properties]

Symbol Properties of Menu and Script Class
[image: Symbol Properties of Menu and Script Class]

Answer (score 0):

Either: the button you are targeting is incorrect..
Your error reads: access to undefined property button_main_quit //check the spelling "button_main_quit"
Also you should use debug mode it will tell you where the error is

Another: the button is declared on a different frame after the instance was already assigned.

An example:

Lets say you have two timelines the top is named actions the second is named content: in the top actions timeline frame 1 you add an event Enter-Frame function for example: then you add a listener for a button call it "btn_1".Now on the content layer, you add the button but on the 5th frame on the content layer:

now you will have the error because the button was not on the stage to be assigned ready for the listener we had added on the enter-Frame function on frame one.
Hopefully you get the idea.